# I am trying to create an op amp based negative voltage regulator

Tags: simulation, circuits, circuit-design

I am trying to find simulate an op amp based linear regulator negative voltage regulator circuit. 
I have done the circuit for positive voltages, but does not know how to do it for negative voltage. Anyone could help me?  I dont know how to connect the op amp. 
I have included a screenshot of my simulation
[image: my simulation]

Comment: Can you please clarify your objective by adding additional details to the question? What is the part number of the op-amp? What is the desired output. What is the input? What is the part number for the zener diode?

Comment: all the part numbers can be seen on the simulation. I want to have a steady 5 V output. Input is 230 rms (50Hz) ac input.

Comment: Are you looking for -5V output? How about using an inverting op-amp circuit? Also not sure what you are trying to do with the op amp on this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question but was able to solve it. I've attached a picture of my circuit. I know this was asked but I hope this helps someone. The Supply rail is attached to the rippled power supply. Whether it's stable or rippled doesn't affect the functionality noticeably (as long as it's above the minimum Supply) [image: op amp based negative voltage regulator]

Answer (score 0):

Below is a good example of configuring the op-amp based voltage regulator.

[image]

Take look at [Op-amp voltage regulator concept](https://www.circuitlib.com/index.php/lessons/96-op-amp-voltage-regulator-concept) post, this might help answer some of your questions.

References:

- [Basics of Linear Regulators](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/linear_reg_basic_appli-e.pdf)

Comment: But is this for negative voltage, because i built it and does not work for negative voltage

Comment: Are you looking for -5V output? How about reversing the D1, and replacing the npn transistor with an pnp? Not too sure who this will work, but just a thought. Or might consider the using the solution to previous answer, and reversing the zener and replacing the npn transistor with pnp.